# Connecting php to MS SQL server 2008

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008

I need a connection script of php and MS SQL:
in trying the following but it doesn't work

```
$server = 'MVEKELDG156\SQLEXPRESS'; $username   = 'EDUC.PWV.GOV.ZA\Mveke.L';    
$password   = 'password@'; $database    = 'SAMS_EMIS_Warehouses';       
if(!mysql_connect($server, $username, $password)) { exit('Error: could not 
establish database connection'); } if(!mysql_select_db($database)) { 
exit('Error: could not select the database'); }
```

Comment: I'm not surprised it didn't work, you forgot to enter the code!

Comment: $server     = 'MVEKELDG156\SQLEXPRESS';
$username = 'EDUC.PWV.GOV.ZA\Mveke.L';
$password = 'password@';
$database = 'SAMS_EMIS_Warehouses';

if(!mysql_connect($server, $username, $password))
{
  exit('Error: could not establish database connection');
}
if(!mysql_select_db($database))
{
  exit('Error: could not select the database');
}

Answer (score 1):

The MSSQL extension is enabled by adding `extension=php_mssql.dll` to `php.ini`.

To get these functions to work, you have to compile PHP with --with-mssql[=DIR] , where DIR is the FreeTDS install prefix. And FreeTDS should be compiled using --enable-msdblib .

More References :

[**Installation**](http://php.net/manual/en/mssql.installation.php)

**[How to use PHP to connect to sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632607/how-to-use-php-to-connect-to-sql-server)**

**[Connecting to an SQL Server Database with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468160/connecting-to-an-sql-server-database-with-php)**

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
$myServer = "localhost";
$myUser = "your_name";
$myPass = "your_password";
$myDB = "SAMS_EMIS_Warehouses";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
or die("Couldn't open database $myDB
```

Source [How to connect to MS SQL Server database](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/connect_mssql_database.php)